# Redirect subdomain to main domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I'm dealing with a site that supports both English and Spanish, and I'd like to know how to redirect all the requests to the language-specific subdomains to the main domain (en.mysite.com and es.mysite.com to mysite.com).

The whole site is programmed in PHP and it has a main script `index.php` that processes the `language` and `section` GET parameters and displays stuff accordingly.

Now, I tried to do the following in the .htaccess file in the root of mysite.com. I think it clarifies what I'm trying to do:

```
RewriteEngine On

# English redirects

RewriteRule ^en.mysite.com$ index.php?language=English&section=Main
RewriteRule ^en.mysite.com/store$ index.php?language=English&section=Store
RewriteRule ^en.mysite.com/create_account$ index.php?language=English&section=CreateAcc

# Spanish redirects

RewriteRule ^es.mysite.com$ index.php?language=Spanish&section=Feed
RewriteRule ^es.mysite.com/comprar$ index.php?language=Spanish&section=Store
RewriteRule ^es.mysite.com/crear_cuenta$ index.php?language=Spanish&section=CreateAcc
```

But this doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include the hostname as part of the match in a `RewriteRule`, as it only matches against the URI. You'll need to use a separate `RewriteCond` that matches against the hostname *for each of your rules*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?language=English&section=Main

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^store$ /index.php?language=English&section=Store

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^create_account$ /index.php?language=English&section=CreateAcc
```

Then the spanish rewrites:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?language=English&section=Feed

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^comprar$ /index.php?language=English&section=Store

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^crear_cuenta$ /index.php?language=English&section=CreateAcc
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I don't know if it works though, I ended up using subdirectories because they are much easy to handle than subdomains.